# Can't consume context in pure-react-carousel

Tags: reactjs, pure-react-carousel

I want to get the current slide index, so I'm trying to consume the CarouselContext. This is what I got and used from the documentation:

```
const carouselContext = useContext(CarouselContext);
const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(carouselContext.state.currentSlide);
  
useEffect(() => {
  function onChange() {
    setCurrentSlide(carouselContext.state.currentSlide);         
    console.log(currentSlide)
  }
  carouselContext.subscribe(onChange);
  return () => carouselContext.unsubscribe(onChange);
}, [carouselContext]);

return <CarouselProvider style={{ height: 'fit-content', marginLeft: '10%', marginRight: '10%'}} 
  isPlaying={true}
  infinite={true} 
  naturalSlideHeight={125} 
  naturalSlideWidth={100} 
  isIntrinsicHeight={true} 
  lockOnWindowScroll={true} 
  totalSlides={3} 
  visibleSlides={1} 
  currentSlide={1}
>
  <Slider style={{padding: '19px 260px'}}>
    <Slide index={0}>
      <TestimonialCard/>
    </Slide>
    <Slide index={1}>
      <TestimonialCard/>
    </Slide>
    <Slide index={2}>
      <TestimonialCard/>
    </Slide>
  </Slider>
</CarouselProvider>
```

But when I run this code, this is what I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
```

Clearly, carouselContext is undefined, and trying to read carouselContext.state.currentSlide is giving me this error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the code of the component creating the context?

Comment: In some parent component, you must wrap the component in `<CarouselProvider>` - see the tutorial: https://github.com/express-labs/pure-react-carousel#-tutorial

Comment: Have you done al the preparation steps outlined here: https://github.com/express-labs/pure-react-carousel#-tutorial ?

Comment: I have wrapped my component with <CarouselProvider>, as mentioned in the documentation. I'm getting this error after following the tutorial

Comment: the <Slider > should be a separate file wrapped in HOC.

Comment: A bit late to this, but to be able to use a Context from a component, the `Provider` of the Context needs to wrap that component. So a solution would be to move everything inside the `CarouselProvider` inside a new component, and consume the `Context` from that component.